# Workflow rule only triggering for admins

Tags: workflow, profile, email-alert

I have a workflow rule that sends an email notification to the user who gets a lead assigned.

This works just fine when is a System Administrator to assign the lead to someone; when this is done from another user though, it doesn't work. The email won't get sent.

I have gone through profile permissions related to emails many times but can't find anything related that might cause this problem.

What could it be?

EDIT: debug log for the user shows that rule is not being evaluated. That's very weird as all criterias are correctly met.

[image]

Comment: how do you know the WFR executes when the running user is not a sysad? try turning debug log on for that running user and then inspect

Comment: just posted a debug log on main post

Comment: Is workflow valuation Criteria set to 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.' ?

Comment: Yeah, it is ...

Comment: Is the record already edited to meet the criteria and you are editing some other field?

Comment: please [edit] your post to include the workflow criteria.  Does the user have permissions to the fields referenced in the criteria?

Comment: I think I found the problem. Criteria's are basically 2 checks on lead owner field NOT EQUAL to 2 admin users. I tried switching the criteria to another user, with another profile, and it works fine. Somehow it can't evaluate criteria on those two users. My initial guess was that this has to do with role hierarchy, but those two admins have no role assigned, while the running user does. Could this be the issue?